# Find a subgradient of a real function

Tags: convex-analysis, subgradient, non-smooth-analysis

Let $f(x)=\chi_{\{-1\}}(x)+I_{[-1,1]}(x)$, where $\chi_{A}(x)=1$ when $x\in A$ and $\chi_{A}(x)=0$ when $x\notin A$, and $I$ is the indicator funcion (which is zero in its domain and infinity otherwise). I want to calculate the subgradient of $f$ at $x=-1$. So,
$$x^*\in \partial f(-1) \Leftrightarrow x^*(x+1)\le f(x)-f(-1), \qquad \mbox{for all }x\in \mathbb{R}.$$
The last expression is equivalent to
$$x^*\in \partial f(-1) \Leftrightarrow x^*(x+1)\le f(x)-1, \qquad \mbox{for all }x\in \mathbb{R},$$
by the definition of $f$. How can I get this subgradient? It is my intuition that it must be the empty set, but I am not sure how to prove it. Please, any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Pick $x=-1+1/n$, $n\ge 2$ in the inequality defining the sub gradients.
$$
\frac{1}{n}x^*\le-1
$$
and, therefore, $x^*\le -n$ for all natural $n$. No real number $x^*$ satisfies this condition.